# iOS app with in-house distribution certificate crashes after some point in time

Tags: ios, iphone

We have an in-house iOS app that can be installed and use without any issues. However, after a couple of days, it stops working. The app crashes immediately when opened. I checked on the iOS logs and found the following logs:

```
Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1050c2be0; application<appdomain>:<invalid>> with error: <NSError: 0x280e01f80; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; reason: "Launch failed."> {
underlyingError = <NSError: 0x280fe3060; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 85>;
```

}

Any idea what causing the issue? Thank you!

Comment: What sort of signing are you using? Ad-hoc? Enterprise? Do you have a paid developer membership?  Does the device have access to the internet?

Comment: We're actually using a third-party merchant to distribute the app. The merchant manages the signing so that it can be installed on any ios devices.

Comment: They still need to use one of the two methods I mentioned. They are either creating ad-hoc builds that include your list of Device ids or they are using an enterprise signing certificate (and violating their agreement with Apple by doing so). There is no way to get non-Apple signed apps to run indefinitely. That is a fundamental part of iOS.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to sort this out? Facing the same issue.